# Python - Random frequency for changing values in a list

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list that contains two lists and I am looking to randomly select one of the values within both of these lists and then multiply them by 0.5

For example, I receive a list like this:

```
[[-0.03680804604507722, 0.022112919584121357], [0.05806232738548797, -0.004015137642131433]]
```

Comment: I have taken a look at using random choice but I also want to put the value back into the list at the same index value.

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like you want to do is iterate through your list of lists, and at each list, randomly select an index, multiply the value at that index by 0.5 and place it back in the list.

```
import random
l = [[-0.03680804604507722, 0.022112919584121357], [0.05806232738548797, -0.004015137642131433]]

# for each sub list in the list
for sub_l in l:
   # select a random integer between 0, and the number of elements in the sub list
   rand_index = random.randrange(len(sub_l))

   # and then multiply the value at that index by 0.5 
   # and store back in sub list
   sub_l[rand_index] = sub_l[rand_index] * 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `randint` and the length of the list.

```
from random import randint

lst = [[-0.03680804604507722, 0.022112919584121357], [0.05806232738548797, -0.004015137642131433]]

for L in lst:
    L[randint(0, len(L) - 1)] *= 0.5
```